# configure.jam: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, boost-build

I have installed boost c++ library, "boost_1_63_0" to use with MinGW compiler on windows 8.1. I am also using boost-build. I have build the library using the command bootstrap.bat and now there is bjam.exe file in BOOST_ROOT. I also set the toolset option "using gcc ;" in "user-config.jam" file in boost-build directory. But still i am facing following error message while running command

> bjam --show-libraries

...........Here is console output..................

### [image: [console output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZj5l.png)

Please identify which configure.jam file it is and what to configure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have build the library using the command bootstrap.bat" -- that doesn't build the library, it just prepares the build system (e.g. compiles bjam) so you can build it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. You mean bjam --show-libraries command will work after i build it? Whereas i think above command should show at least all libraries and then i can choose which one to build, am i wrong?